# create breadcrumb with MvcSiteMap in mvc5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, mvcsitemapprovider

i want to create breadcrumb with MvcSiteMap in mvc5.
i wrote below code.
but i want to when i click on first , second , ... their Id pass to View.
but it dose not work. i do it right?

```
//Controller Name=News

Home
News
     first     //id=1
     second   //id=2
     third   // id=3
About


<mvcSiteMapNode title="Home" controller="Home" action="Index">
<mvcSiteMapNode  title="News" controller="News" action="Index" key="News">
</mvcSiteMapNode>
<mvcSiteMapNode title="About" controller="About" action="Index"/>
```

```
   [MvcSiteMapNode(Title = "News", ParentKey = "News")]
    public ActionResult News(int id)
    {
        ViewBag.id = id;
        return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

As stated in [the documentation](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Routing-Basics), you *must* configure all custom route parameters (including id) explicitly. You can create a 1 to 1 relationship with the action method by including the key in PreservedRouteParameters or you can create a 1 to many relationship with the action by creating a separate node for every route value combination.

## 1 to 1 Relationship

**Using [XML](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Defining-sitemap-nodes-in-XML):**

```
<mvcSiteMapNode title="News" controller="News" action="News" preservedRouteParameters="id"/>
```

**Or Using [.NET Attributes](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Defining-sitemap-nodes-using-.NET-attributes):**

```
[MvcSiteMapNode(Title = "News", ParentKey = "News", PreservedRouteParameters = "id")]
public ActionResult News(int id)
{
    ViewBag.id = id;
    return View();
}
```

> Note: Using this method, the URLs will only resolve correctly in the SiteMapPath HTML helper, and you may need to fix the title and visibility of nodes manually as [explained here](http://www.shiningtreasures.com/post/2013/09/02/how-to-make-mvcsitemapprovider-remember-a-user-position#forcing-a-match).

## 1 to Many Relationship

**Using [XML](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Defining-sitemap-nodes-in-XML):**

```
<mvcSiteMapNode title="Article 1" controller="News" action="News" id="1"/>
<mvcSiteMapNode title="Article 2" controller="News" action="News" id="2"/>
<mvcSiteMapNode title="Article 3" controller="News" action="News" id="3"/>
```

**Or Using [.NET Attributes](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Defining-sitemap-nodes-using-.NET-attributes):**

```
[MvcSiteMapNode(Title = "Article 1", ParentKey = "News", Attributes = @"{ ""id"": 1 }")]
[MvcSiteMapNode(Title = "Article 2", ParentKey = "News", Attributes = @"{ ""id"": 2 }")]
[MvcSiteMapNode(Title = "Article 3", ParentKey = "News", Attributes = @"{ ""id"": 3 }")]
public ActionResult News(int id)
{
    ViewBag.id = id;
    return View();
}
```

**Or Using a [Dynamic Node Provider](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Defining-sitemap-nodes-using-IDynamicNodeProvider):**

With Definition Node in XML:

```
<mvcSiteMapNode  title="News" controller="News" action="Index" key="News">
    // Setup definition node in XML (won't be in the SiteMap)
    // Any attributes you put here will be the defaults in the dynamic node provider, but can be overridden there.
    <mvcSiteMapNode dynamicNodeProvider="MyNamespace.NewsDynamicNodeProvider, MyAssembly" controller="News" action="News"/>
</mvcSiteMapNode>
```

Or With Definition Node in .NET Attributes:

```
// Setup definition node as a .NET Attribute (won't be in the SiteMap)
// Any properties you put here will be the defaults in the dynamic node provider, but can be overridden there.
[MvcSiteMapNode(DynamicNodeProvider = "MyNamespace.NewsDynamicNodeProvider, MyAssembly")]
public ActionResult News(int id)
{
    ViewBag.id = id;
    return View();
}
```

Dynamic Node Provider Implementation (required for either of the 2 definition nodes above):

```
public class NewsDynamicNodeProvider 
    : DynamicNodeProviderBase 
{ 
    public override IEnumerable<DynamicNode> GetDynamicNodeCollection(ISiteMapNode node) 
    {
        using (var db = new EnityContext())
        {
            // Create a node for each news article 
            foreach (var news in db.News) 
            { 
                var dynamicNode = new DynamicNode(); 
                dynamicNode.Title = news.Title;
                dynamicNode.ParentKey = "News";
                dynamicNode.RouteValues.Add("id", news.Id);

                yield return dynamicNode;
            }
        }
    } 
}
```