# Infinite loading after installing MVCSiteMapProvider.MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvcsitemapprovider

I have a problem with the MVCSiteMapProvider.MVC5 Nuget pack.
I saw a tutorial to create a dynamic breadcrumb using MVCSiteMapProvider.MVC4. I'm using MVC 5 for my project (I don't know why I used this version, this is my first project so I decided to use the most recent one).
Anyway, I followed this tutorial and everything seems have worked as expected. But when I start my project I get an infinite loading on my HomeController Index.

Everything worked before installing that pack. Here some code that I used.

This is my HomeController. Very basic, I only use this to change some class in the shared layout, for now.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace CoinVault_Web.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Home
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.HomeButtonClass = "SectionSelected";
            return View();
        }

    }
}
```

This is the view linked to the Index action, some text and CKEditor tests

```
 @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Home";
    }
    <h2 class="page-header">Home</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor 
        incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis 
        nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
        Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu 
        fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt 
        in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <textarea class="ehzsoft-texteditor" id="editor1" name="editor1"></textarea>
    <script type="text/javascript"> CKEDITOR.replace('editor1'); </script>
```

In the shared layout I load the _Breadcrumb.cshtml to display the breadcrumb, and the code contained is

```
@Html.MvcSiteMap().SiteMapPath()
```

Mvc.Sitemap is as default and I didn't edit Web.config after the installation.

Any help? Is there any possibility to downgrade to MVC 4?
Thanks.

UPDATE:

Tutorial followed: [create breadcrumb with MvcSiteMap in mvc5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27076680/create-breadcrumb-with-mvcsitemap-in-mvc5)

MVCSiteMapProvider.MVC4 is the pack that I know it work, not the one I installed.

Infinite Loading means blank screen with page loading in IIS server when I start the project locally.

Comment: What do you mean by 'infinite loading'?  Please also provide a link to the tutorial that you followed.

Comment: Are you saying that you installed `MvcSiteMapProvider.MVC4` into an MVC 5 web site? You should be installing `MvcSiteMapProvider.MVC5`.

Comment: It is unclear why this would happen. Try following the [test drive tutorial](http://www.shiningtreasures.com/post/2013/08/07/MvcSiteMapProvider-40-a-test-drive). Also, make sure you DO NOT install version 4.6.20 because the NuGet packages for that version are broken.

Comment: Do you happen to be using OWIN? There is a similar issue reported [here](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/issues/421#issuecomment-173546440) with a possible solution.